# Set first day of week in Stanford NLP in time expression extraction

Tags: stanford-nlp

I want to set the first day of week in Stanford NLP in time expression extraction. The default is Monday, I want to set Saturday as the first day of week.

I tried to change  "Basic dates/times" section in defs.sutime.txt and setting SUNDAY = DayOfWeek(1);

but once I did, I got a wrong date extraction. Any advises ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The ISO8601 standard specifies Monday as the first day of the week (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates).  So DayOfWeek(1) will always map to the concept of Monday.  If you would like to have different notation for the day of week, you can remap the output to interpret the day of the week differently.